# INSERT INTO .. SELECT .. unique constraint violation

Tags: sql, sql-server, unique-constraint

I'm running a stored procedure that selects values my temp table and inserts them into the database like so:

```
 INSERT INTO emails (EmailAddress)   (
     SELECT
       DISTINCT eit.EmailAddress
     FROM #EmailInfoTemp eit
       LEFT JOIN emails ea
         ON eit.EmailAddress = ea.EmailAddress
     WHERE ea.EmailAddressID IS NULL   )
```

On rare cases(~ once every couple of hours on a server that handles thousands of requests a minute), I then receive a unique constraint error "Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint�".. on an index on the EmailAddress column.

I can confirm that I am not passing in duplicate values. Even if I was, it should be caught by the DISTINCT.

-SQL Server 2008
-Stored proc + not using transactions + JDBC callablestatement

Could it happen that between the SELECT and the ensuing INSERT, there was another call to the same/different stored proc that completed an INSERT with similiar data? If so, what would be the best way to prevent that?

Some ideas: We have many duplicate instances of "clients" who communicate with this one SQL Server at once in production, so my first reaction was a concurrency issue, but I can't seem to replicate it myself. That's the best guess I had, but it's gone nowhere so far. This does not happen on our staging environment where the load is insignificant compared to the production environment. That was the main reason I started looking into concurrency issues.

Comment: NULL value in EmailAddress on both sides might violate unique key constraint. If this column is nullable you might rewrite insert as `not exists`.

Comment: Good point. I do check against nulls in the code, but I suppose I could check it again in sql.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is probably caused by two sessions executing an insert at the same time.

You can make your SQL code safer by using [MERGE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx).  As Aaron Bertrand's comment says (thanks!), [you have to include a `with (holdlock)` hint to make `merge` really safe](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2009/01/31/UPSERT-Race-Condition-With-MERGE.aspx).

```
; merge emails e with (holdlock)
using   #EmailInfoTemp eit
on      e.EmailAddress = eit.EmailAddress
when    not matched then insert
        (EmailAddress) values (eit.EmailAddress)
```

The `merge` statement will take appropriate locks to ensure that no other session can sneak in between it's "not matched" check and the "insert".

If you can't use `merge`, you could solve the problem client-side.  Make sure that no two inserts are running at the same time.  This is typically easy to do with a [mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx) or other synchronization construct.

Comment: [`MERGE` is not necessarily safer unless you add a `HOLDLOCK` hint](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2009/01/31/UPSERT-Race-Condition-With-MERGE.aspx).

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Thanks.  The MSDN page for MERGE says "Specifying READPAST with WHEN NOT MATCHED [ BY TARGET ] THEN INSERT may result in INSERT operations that violate UNIQUE constraints."  So I assumed that it was safe unless you specified `readpast`.

Comment: yeah Microsoft is not usually likely to document all of the cases where it might break. The documentation also doesn't talk about [any of these yet-to-be-resolved bugs (scroll to the bottom)](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/02/t-sql-queries/another-merge-bug). :-)